# SQL: Count distinct values from one column based on multiple criteria in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, multiple-columns

**I am trying to do count distinct values based on multiple criteria.**
Sample data exercise included below.

```
           Table1
╔════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ Bug ID ║ Status ║ Test ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════╣
║      1 ║ Open   ║ w    ║
║      2 ║ Closed ║ w    ║
║      3 ║ Open   ║ w    ║
║      4 ║ Open   ║ x    ║
║      4 ║ Open   ║ x    ║
║      5 ║ Closed ║ x    ║
║      5 ║ Closed ║ x    ║
║      5 ║ Closed ║ y    ║
║      6 ║ Open   ║ z    ║
║      6 ║ Open   ║ z    ║
║      6 ║ Open   ║ z    ║
║      7 ║ Closed ║ z    ║
║      8 ║ Closed ║ z    ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════╝
      Desired Query Results
╔══════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ Test ║ Open Bugs ║ Total Bugs ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ w    ║         2 ║          3 ║
║ x    ║         1 ║          2 ║
║ y    ║         0 ║          1 ║
║ z    ║         1 ║          3 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

A given Bug can be found in multiple Tests, multiple times for the same Test(ex: 6), or both (ex: 5).

**The following query works fine to accurately deliver 'Total Bugs'**

```
SELECT
Test,
COUNT(DISTINCT Bug ID) AS "Total Bugs"
FROM
Table1
GROUP BY Test
```

**My research has led me to variations on the following query.  They miss the distinct bugs and therefore return the incorrect results (shown below the query) for the 'Open Bugs' column**

```
SELECT
Test,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status <> 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Open Bugs"
FROM
Table1
GROUP BY Test
```

```
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ Test ║ Open Bugs ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║ w    ║         2 ║
║ x    ║         2 ║
║ y    ║         0 ║
║ z    ║         3 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

**Of course my end result must deliver both count columns in one table (rather than using separate queries as I have done for demonstration purposes).**

I would like not rely on multiple subqueries because my live example will have more than two columns with counts from the same table but various criteria.

I am working with SQL Server (not sure release).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068192/8614314

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can have a conditional `count(distinct)` by using this code:

```
SELECT Test, COUNT(DISTINCT "Bug ID") AS "Total Bugs",
count(distinct (CASE WHEN "Status" <> 'Closed' THEN "Bug ID" END)) as "Open Bugs"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Test
```

The `case` statement checks the condition.  When true, it returns the `Bug ID`.  When not present, it defaults to NULL, so the id does not get counted.

Comment: Extremely helpful.  I was not aware you could reference columns after the 'THEN'.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you - replaced a bunch of inefficient, hard to understand joins with something like this.