# Counting Values based on distinct values from another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to calculate how many orderlines there are based on the orderlineNo being distinct. Each OrderNo is different BUT the OrderLineNo is the same for each order.
i.e. 9 lines on a order then order lines number will go from 1 - 9. The same if on another order there are 3 orderlines they will go from 1 - 3

But in orderlineno there could be orderline numbers that are the same - for this I only want to count it once

Example:

```
OrderNo        OrderLineNo
987654             1
987654             2
987654             2
987654             3
987654             4
987654             5
987654             6
987654             7
```

The total order lines here is 7. There are two order lines with 2 and I want them to only be counted once.

Is this possible using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, Although this works, it shows the total per order,I just need the complete total.

Comment: Instead of commenting your question you should  edit it and add the desired result and a complete sample. You don't need to show hundreds, but it would be helpful to see one which contains more than one `OrderNo`. Also, if you are referring to my answer below then comment that instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Comment: Based on the logic of your table, why not just select the MAX OrderLineNo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add DISTINCT to a COUNT:

```
select OrderNo, count(distinct OrderLineNo)
from tab
group by OrderNo;
```

Or if OrderLineNo always starts with 1 and increases without gaps:

```
select OrderNo, max(OrderLineNo)
from tab
group by OrderNo;
```

Edit:

Based on the comment it's not a count per OrderNo, but a global count. You need to use a Derived Table:

```
select count(*)
from
 (select distinct OrderNo, OrderLineNo
  from tab
 ) as dt;
```

or

```
select sum(n)
from
 (select OrderNo, max(OrderLineNo) as n
  from tab
  group by OrderNo
 ) as dt;
```

or

```
select sum(Dist_count)
from
 ( select OrderNo,count(distinct OrderLineNo) as Dist_count
   from Table1
   group by OrderNo
 ) as dt
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want this:

```
SELECT OrderNo, COUNT(distinct OrderLineNo) as CntDistOrderLineNoPerOrderNo
FROM Table1
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

<kbd>[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da190/2/0)</kbd>

So for every `OrderNo` the count of dictinct `OrderLineNo` which is 7 for 987654.

If you instead want the  sum of all distinct OrderLineNo as commented.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT OrderNo,
         MAX(OrderLineNo) as MaxOrderLineNoPerOrderNo
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY OrderNo
)
SELECT SUM(MaxOrderLineNoPerOrderNo) AS SumOrderLineNoPerOrderNo
FROM CTE
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0097c/10/0)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry I meant to comment on this one. Yes this works But it shows all Order No;s with the respective total. How can I get it to show The complete total of all of them.

Comment: So you want the sum of all distinct OrderLineNo?

Comment: Yes, a sum of all distinct orderlines (but distinct on orderno level)

Comment: I edited your SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2fb5a/1
If you run it will give you 7 & 6 (total = 13) if you remove "Orderno," and group by. it will only give you 7. i need the 13 :)

Comment: @Crampo: have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Distinct` in `count` aggregate

```
select count(distinct OrderLineNo) as Dist_count
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without distinct, but it requires applying `group by` twice:

```
select orderNo , count(*) from
  (select orderNo from tbl group by orderNo,orderlineNo) t1 group by orderNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer and modified it as your need:

```
SELECT DEVICE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ANOMALY_SEVERITY = 'Critical' THEN 'Critical' END) as 'Critical', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN ANOMALY_SEVERITY = 'High' THEN 'High' END) as 'High',
COUNT(CASE WHEN ANOMALY_SEVERITY = 'Medium' THEN 'Medium' END) as 'Medium', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN ANOMALY_SEVERITY = 'Low' THEN 'Low' END) as 'Low',
COUNT(CASE WHEN ANOMALY = 'True' THEN 'Total' END) as 'Total'
FROM <table_name> WHERE ANOMALY='True' GROUP BY DEVICE
```