# Count in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the following SQL query:

```
select 
    FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid,
    FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid 
from 
    FilteredPhoneCall 
Inner Join 
    FilteredSystemUser on FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid in (FilteredPhoneCall.createdby)
Inner Join 
    FilteredLead on FilteredLead.leadid = FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid
where 
    DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.createdon, GETDATE()) = 0 
    and FilteredLead.statecode = 0 
    and FilteredLead.ownerid = FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
    and FilteredPhoneCall.statecode = '1' 
    and FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjecttypecode = 4
    and FilteredPhoneCall.createdby in ('c2dd1ddc-0374-e611-80dc-00155d3d1992', '53cfbe3a-a09a-e611-80df-00155dce24d0')
```

and get the following output

[image]

Here I have two entries in regardingid **97C29D24-BEE2-E611-80F1-00155DCE24EF,091B1CAB-C2E2-E611-80F1-00155DCE24EF** against same system user.so i need to consider this as single entry and get the count other than this the both system users having another two ids.

[image]

I expect the above output
[image]

Comment: Put this search in a subquery and then group and count

Comment: Use count(FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get count of distinct values of a column reference here...
[SQL: Count distinct values from one column based on multiple criteria in other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156717/sql-count-distinct-values-from-one-column-based-on-multiple-criteria-in-other-c)

For your case, try this:

```
   select 
        FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid,
        Count(DISTINCT FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid ) as NoofCall
    from 
        FilteredPhoneCall 
    Inner Join 
        FilteredSystemUser on FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid in (FilteredPhoneCall.createdby)
    Inner Join 
        FilteredLead on FilteredLead.leadid = FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid
    where 
        DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.createdon, GETDATE()) = 0 
        and FilteredLead.statecode = 0 
        and FilteredLead.ownerid = FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
        and FilteredPhoneCall.statecode = '1' 
        and FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjecttypecode = 4
        and FilteredPhoneCall.createdby in ('c2dd1ddc-0374-e611-80dc-00155d3d1992', '53cfbe3a-a09a-e611-80df-00155dce24d0')
    Group by FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count() and group by to achive this.

```
select      COUNT(DISTINCT FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid ) as NoofCall
            ,FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
from        FilteredPhoneCall 
inner Join  FilteredSystemUser
on          FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid in(FilteredPhoneCall.createdby)
Join        FilteredLead
on          FilteredLead.leadid = FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid
where       DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.createdon, GETDATE()) = 0 
    and     FilteredLead.statecode = 0 and FilteredLead.ownerid = FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
    and     FilteredPhoneCall.statecode = '1' and FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjecttypecode = 4
    and     FilteredPhoneCall.createdby in ('c2dd1ddc-0374-e611-80dc-00155d3d1992','53cfbe3a-a09a-e611-80df-00155dce24d0')
    and     FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid in ('c2dd1ddc-0374-e611-80dc-00155d3d1992','53cfbe3a-a09a-e611-80df-00155dce24d0')
   GROUP BY FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
```

Comment: If i use like this its shows 3 records for each system users. But I need to consider the same regadingid as single entry.

Comment: There is duplicate row was available in first four rows.so i need to ignore the duplicate

Comment: can you edit your question show the complete output you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
;with CTE 
      AS (
    select 
        FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid,
        FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid 
    from 
        FilteredPhoneCall 
    Inner Join 
        FilteredSystemUser on FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid in (FilteredPhoneCall.createdby)
    Inner Join 
        FilteredLead on FilteredLead.leadid = FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjectid
    where 
        DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.createdon, GETDATE()) = 0 
        and FilteredLead.statecode = 0 
        and FilteredLead.ownerid = FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid
        and FilteredPhoneCall.statecode = '1' 
        and FilteredPhoneCall.regardingobjecttypecode = 4
        and FilteredPhoneCall.createdby in ('c2dd1ddc-0374-e611-80dc-00155d3d1992', '53cfbe3a-a09a-e611-80df-00155dce24d0') )

        select count(CTE.systemuserid) as myCOUNT,CTE.systemuserid,CTE.regardingobjectid from CTE
        group by  CTE.systemuserid,CTE.regardingobjectid
```

---

[image]

Comment: Please go through my expected result. i need to collapse duplicate rows as 1 and then calculate the rows

Comment: @User Above query shows same result what you posted in OUTPUT IMAGE

Comment: Here c2dd... system user id having 3 records and the 53cf... system user having 3 records. But there is some values are duplicates.So I need to take a single record in first set of duplicate and take another single record from the second set of duplicate.

Comment: The last two rows are having  separate values so we need to take and count this.